# Optimization for GetSecret with Azure Keyvault

Tags: optimization, azure-keyvault, c#-6.0

Our main goal for now is optimising the a processing service.
The service has a system-assigned managed identity with accespolicies that allow to get a secret.
This service makes 4 calls to a keyvault. The first one takes a lot longer than the others. I'm scratching my head, because the Managed Identity token takes 91µs to obtain.  [Application Insights image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akoef.png)

I changed the way the tokens were obtained. The program only obtains it once and keeps using that same token for other round trips. I did this by making the CredentialClass AddScoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the question is why the first call takes more time. If yes, just throwing in a couple of generic reasons which might contribute:

- HTTPS handshake on the first call might take time
- The client might need to create a connection pool
- In case of Azure Key Vault, the first call does two round-trips AFAIK, first for auth, the second for the real payload